# Twenty Twelve theme search returns Nothing Found

Tags: themes, search, theme-twenty-twelve

I am using WP 3.6.1 With Theme Twenty Twelve. The search will not return any thing. No matter what term I use it just goes to the search return page and says the following

> Nothing Found
>
> Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with
>   some different keywords

I have tried Deactivating every plugin and using different themes I have tried Search plugins that use the themes search.php file and I continue to get these same results. I have just add the plugin Relevanssi but its the same issue no changes. Here is the code from the search.php I have not made any changes and IM using the default search widget.  I have tried all day long to research and find a solution I am not sure where else to look or what to try next.

```
<section id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->
```